# Let U be a linear operator in a dimensionally finite vector space V

Tags: linear-algebra

If $\text{rank} $($U^{m}$)= $\text{rank}(U^{m+1})$ for some positive integer m, then rank $(U^{m})=$rank $(U^{k})$ for any positive integer $k\geq m$

Why this is true?, I have been looking for the answer in several books and I do not know why it is true, my teacher said it was trivial but I would like to know why it happens

Comment: Show that the range spaces are nested, that is ${\cal R} A^{k+1} \subset {\cal R} A^{k}$. Then show that if ${\cal R} A^{k+1} = {\cal R} A^{k}$ for some particular $k$ then ${\cal R} A^{m} = {\cal R} A^{k}$ for all $m \ge k$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $W=U^m(V)$. Then $U^{m+1}(V)=U(W)$. On the other hand,$$U^{m+1}(V)=U^m\bigl(U(V)\bigr)\subset U^m(V)=W.$$But $\dim U^{m+1}(V)=\dim U^m(V)=\dim W$. So, since $U^{m+1}(V)$ is a subspace of $W$ which has the same dimension as $W$, they are equal. So, the restriction of $U$ to $W$ is an isomorphism. And now$$U^{m+2}(V)=U\bigl(U^{m+1}(V)\bigr)=U\bigl(U^m(V)\bigr)=U^{m+1}(V)=U^m(V).$$And so on…

Comment: But who is W? because it seems to me that the L.T goes from V to V

Comment: I think I already understood you because $dimU^{m+2} = dimU^{m+1} = dimU^m$ have the same dimension so it doesn't matter how big $dimU^{m+k} $ is for some k in positive integers they will always have the same dimension so they are equal

Comment: Then at the end of your explanation it is only argued that if we take a k in the positive integers, and then we decompose the U we will arrive at where dim $ U^{m + k} = dim U^{m}$

Comment: I *defined* $W$ as the range of $U$. So, I don't understand why you are asking “who is $W$?”